# How to make items af a ListView float (like in CSS)

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt-quick

In QML, you can decorate items of a listview vertically or horizontally. But is it possible to make items float like what we do in css? I mean something like this:
 ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**
| Item1  Item2  Item3 |
| Item4  Item5  Item6 |
| Item7                    |
|**__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**|

Answer (score 1):

The solution was easy, adding for other people with the same problem:
There is another component for this usage called GridView, it does exactly the job.

Comment: You can alse use Flow item

Comment: Yeah, thanks, in my case girds suit better, but generally flow does the exact thing of css float in qml.